# Create a compound partition key in azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a Stream Analytics job pulling messages from an Event Hub and pushing the data into Table Storage. This all works fine, but I would like the Partition Key to be a compound key of two of the columns in the EventHub message. I cannot see anywhere how to set the partition key to be the concatenation of the two columns

Can someone tell me how to create a compound partition key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the CONCAT command .

```
CONCAT ( string_value1, string_value2 [, string_valueN ] )
```

In the stream analytics query to output azure table storage you need to do something like

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(column1, column2) AS partitionKey, 
    column3  AS rowKey

INTO
    [Event-Hub-output-table]
FROM
    [Event-Hub-input]
```

The partitionkey has to be a string and should be selected as such it makes a valid partition in your dataset.

Comment: In fact his is the way I did it in the end

Comment: oh ok. I think this is the simple approach to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to this by creating an aliased column (which is set at the concatenation of two of the columns) in the Stream Analytics query. Then using that new column as the partition key.